# Failure sending mail using Gmail SMTP

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'm posting here because I have been trying a lot of times sending an email through a program in c# (Visual Studio 2015), but I can't. The exception is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: Failure sending mail.

And My Code is the following:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text); 
SmtpClient smclient = new SmtpClient("smpt.gmail.com", 587); //465
smclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("haroncv@gmail.com", "(password)");
smclient.EnableSsl = true;
smclient.Send(msg);
MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent");
```

Where:

```
from.text = "haroncv@gmail.com"
to.text = "haroncv@gmail.com"
subject.text = "Sending email"
body.text = "hello world, how are you"
```

Comment: where exactly does the error occur when you step into the code?

Comment: Could you share the stack trace?

Comment: The error occur in:

smpt.Send(msg);

Comment: Just to check, is the smpt rather than smtp, in your smpt.gmail.com reference, a typo just in your post?

Comment: could be because you're running locally or because the credentials are wrong. Just guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are experiencing the same issue i experienced here. Hope this helps.
[Sending email from specific server gives socket forbidden error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161317/sending-email-from-specific-server-gives-socket-forbidden-error/43196219#43196219)